# Vertically aligning/spacing list items

Tags: jquery, html, css

Are you able to space a navigation list to have vertical spaces between certain `<li>` tags using CSS and not JavaScript & JQuery?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ssqnY/

It needs to be responsive with the height of the containing div or window height.
The structure of the navigation list is below:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How are you calculating height? is it in percent?

Comment: Fiddle works...So what is the problem ?

Comment: @Ani OP wants it only in CSS, that's the challenge... ;)

Comment: you can also add the class to the li you want to add the space below/above using CSS padding/margin.

Answer (score 1):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/ssqnY/1/

```
li.spacer {
  margin: 0 0 30% 0;
}
```

Works for responsive too.

Comment: why this `padding` and the rest? a spacing is only did by the `margin` right?

Comment: @PauloRoberto You are correct Sir. I must have copy pasted and forgot to remove :P

Answer (score 0):

You can set vertical spacing to certain `li`'s using CSS this way:
Set your desired `li` with a `spacer` class and then:

```
li.spacer {
  margin: 15% 0;
}
```

You can too, set the first `li` to have a space:

```
li:first {
  margin: 15% 0;
}
```

Or all the `li`'s to have space:

```
li {
  margin: 15% 0;
}
```

Ps: the `15%` value is just an example, you can set what you want to it, you can use maybe a percentage, to become more responsive like `10px`.